# Changing Push certificates from 2 (Sandbox & Production) to 1 certificate for both (Sandbox/Production)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about changing the Push notification certificates and what effect it could have on people using our apps. We now use 2 certificates for Push notifications, one for Sandbox and one for Production.

Apple introduced the option to use 1 certificate for both Production and Sandbox. Let's say I remove the Sandbox en Production certificate and create a new one for both Production and Sandbox and add that certificate to my backend. Would that affect the users that are currently downloaded the app from the App Store?

Thx!

Comment: 1. Sandbox : we can debug and used for local purpose  2. Production : global access,

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke the old certificates, generate new single cert and update it on your backend.

`Push Certificate` is not a part of the deployment of the application it's `only updated on the server side` so it won't affect receiving pushes for the previously downloaded apps.

Everything should work fine.

Comment: If u will revoke the APNS certificate app will not receive push notification

Comment: @Som please read more carefully, I wrote revoke, regenerate and update the cert on backend not just revoke. After switching to Single cert and updating on BE pushes will work fine.